# How to achieve desired results in multidimensional array? C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to achieve the output by using `multidimensional array` which I can get by using `KeyValuePair`.

Input:

```
var foodPair = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Pizza", "Italian"},
    {"Curry", "Indian"},
    {"Masala", "Indian"}
};

var teamPreference = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Jose", "Italian" },
    {"John", "Indian" },
    {"Sarah", "Thai" },
    {"Mary", "*" }
};

* means give everything
If selected food type is not available than give nothing. i.e Thai
```

Output:

```
Jose, Pizza
John, Curry
John, Masala
Mary, Pizza
Mary, Curry
Mary, Masala
```

Working Result by using `KeyValuePair<string, string>`:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNdlfy

I want to achieve same result by using `string[,]` but I don't know how to insert in dimensional array. Basically I am trying to learn how `multidimensional arrays` works by doing this kind of example.

Comment: Nothing.  When using a Dictionary it is a KeyPairValue with the key being a hash to speed up lookup.  You can also use List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.  A dictionary when storing data takes longer than adding to a list<> because the add dictionary has to put key into the hash table.  So when you don't need the hash for retrieving data or when you want to increase the speed of the writes there is no reason you cannot use a list instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "insert" in any array (single-dimensional or multidimensional). But you can create array with enough space.

```
    var foodPair = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Pizza", "Italian" }, { "Curry", "Indian" }, { "Masala", "Indian" } };
    var teamPreference = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Jose", "Italian" }, { "John", "Indian" }, { "Sarah", "Thai" }, { "Mary", "*" } };
    var results = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    var results2 = new string[10, 2];
    int rowIndex = 0;

    foreach (var teamMember in teamPreference)
    {
        switch (teamMember.Key)
        {
            case "Jose":
                var key = foodPair.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Italian").Key;
                results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, key));
                results2[rowIndex, 0] = teamMember.Key;
                results2[rowIndex, 1] = key;
                rowIndex++;
                break;

            case "John":
                var getAll = foodPair.Where(x => x.Value == "Indian").ToList();
                if (getAll.Any())
                {
                    results.AddRange(getAll.Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, a.Key)));
                }
                foreach (var item in getAll)
                {
                    results2[rowIndex, 0] = teamMember.Key;
                    results2[rowIndex, 1] = item.Key;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                break;

            case "Sarah":
                var c = foodPair.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Thai").Key;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
                {
                    results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, c));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
                {
                    results2[rowIndex, 0] = teamMember.Key;
                    results2[rowIndex, 1] = c;
                    rowIndex++;
                }

                break;

            case "Mary":
                if (teamMember.Value == "*")
                {
                    var everything = foodPair.Keys.ToList();
                    if (everything.Any())
                    {
                        results.AddRange(everything.Select(food => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, food)));
                    }
                    foreach (var item in everything)
                    {
                        results2[rowIndex, 0] = teamMember.Key;
                        results2[rowIndex, 1] = item;
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    if (results.Any())
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", result.Key, result.Value);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Using multidimensional array");

    for (int row = 0; row < rowIndex; row++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", results2[row, 0], results2[row, 1]);
    }
```

But multidimensional array is not suitable data structure for this task. (You can see code with array looks terrible). Data structure that you need is called [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) and the definition for results can look like `var results3 = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();` 
Additional note - you not need using `.Any()` with `foreach` statement. `foreach` is not executed for empty collections.
Good luck with learning C#!

Answer (score 0):

I used `Extension` method to achieve the desired result.

```
public static string[,] FoodPreferenceWithDimensionalArray()
{
    var foodPair = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Pizza", "Italian"},
        {"Curry", "Indian"},
        {"Masala", "Indian"}
    };

    var teamPreference = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Jose", "Italian" },
        {"John", "Indian" },
        {"Sarah", "Thai" },
        {"Mary", "*" }
    };

    var results = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach (var teamMember in teamPreference)
    {
        switch (teamMember.Key)
        {
            case "Jose":
                var italianDish = foodPair.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Italian").Key;
                results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, italianDish));
                break;

            case "John":
                var indianDish = foodPair.Where(x => x.Value == "Indian");
                if (indianDish.Any())
                {
                    results.AddRange(indianDish.Select(dish => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, dish.Key)));
                }
                break;

            case "Sarah":
                var thaiDish = foodPair.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Thai").Key;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thaiDish))
                {
                    results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, thaiDish));
                }
                break;

            case "Mary":
                if (teamMember.Value == "*")
                {
                    var everything = foodPair.Keys.ToList();
                    if (everything.Any())
                    {
                        results.AddRange(everything.Select(food => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(teamMember.Key, food)));
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    var resultIn2DArray = results.To2DArray();
    return resultIn2DArray;
}

// Created extension to convert List to String[,]
public static class Extension
{
    public static string[,] To2DArray<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The list must have non-zero dimensions.");
        }

        var result = new string[list.Count, list.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
           // This is set to 0 since I know the output but will work on this to make it dynamic.
            result[0, i] = list[i].ToString(); 
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your input.